# How to create video from camera?

Tags: unity, camera

I have a 3d scene and a camera; I want to create video file from camera pre-set movements. 
If it is possible, running application by command line (without needed to "show" at video, my camera) .

Is it possible in Unity ?

If yes what's the best approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something assets would do. Look up in the Unity Asset Store.

Comment: You want to run your game in headless mode and render the scene to a video?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [official Unity Recorder asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-recorder-94079). The latest Unity Recorder is available in Preview via the Package Manager from Unity 2018.3+, the asset store version is no longer being updated actively I believe.